# Calling an ASP function from an external ASP file

Tags: website, vbscript, asp

For some reason, I can include an ASP file with the following code:

```
<!--# include virtual="/includes/func.asp" -->
```

But, I have some functions in that file, and I can't call them into my main file. Can someone help? I'm calling them like this:

```
<% my_func() %>
```

..and all I get is an error message, with a link to another webpage. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Thank you for updating my syntax. How did you do that?

Comment: It's a function of the editor.  You can either select it and click Ctrl-K, or select it and click the Binary Format button just above the editor (the button with the 1's and 0's)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBScript, you can call functions in a handful of ways;

1. returnval = functionYaddaYaddaYadda()
2. functionFoo()
3. Call functionBar()

You're essentially trying to #2 with shorthand ASP tags. Use:

```
<%= my_func() %>
```

The "=" is the shorthand way of doing:

```
response.write(my_func())
```

**P.S.** Check out the [MSDN VBScript Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d1wf56tt(VS.85).aspx). There's really not much to VBScript outside of this reference manual. Maybe more elegant tricks but the meat of VBScript can be found on that site.

Comment: Dude, you rock. Thanks man, I'm a major noob with ASP. I appreciate it.

Comment: No problem, dude. :) I should also note that *ASP* type information isn't found on the MSDN reference link I provided. Just VBScript. You can think of ASP as like a mini layer of frosting on top of the cake that is VBScript. For ASP type info, w3schools (http://www.w3schools.com/asp/asp_intro.asp) would probably be a good place to start if you need ASP-centric info. They too have VBscript programming info should you need it.